# Tilt template engine initialization

Tags: ruby, templating, tilt

I just install tilt :

```
gem list
tilt (1.2.2)

ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [universal-darwin9.0]
```

And I simply try the basic example from https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt

tilt.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'haml'
require 'tilt'
template = Tilt::HamlTemplate.new('haml/about.haml')
```

And it throw :

```
./tilt.rb:4: uninitialized constant Tilt (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from tilt.rb:3
```

Any idea ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've named your application file `tilt.rb`, so when you call `require 'tilt'` the file tries to require itself. Your file doesn't define `Tilt`, so you get the error you see.

The error actually happens as the file is being required. It doesn't fall into recursive loop because `require` keeps track of the files that have been required, and doesn't attempt to reload them.

Rename your file to something other than `tilt.rb`, for instance `tilt-test.rb`, and don't leave the original file in the same directory, and it should work.

Incidentally, this doesn't happen in Ruby 1.9, since the current directory isn't on the load path by default.